# NSUrlConnection with table view and search display controller

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am writing an iPhone app which gets data from a mysql database. I am trying to use a search display controller to search the database as the user types input into the search bar, but the problem I am having is that uitableview methods are called before the nsurlconnection methods.

My current coding logic is as follows;

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
//code to start connection

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
//populate array of search results

//Load data into search results
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Does anyone know how to make this work or know of another method of doing this? If something is unclear or you need some more information please let me know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It probably won't address your immediate problem, but I just want to suggest that you should never directly connect to a MySQL database from your app.  If you are connecting to an intermediary (using a web services layer, for example) then you are fine, but it's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `[tableView reloadData]` after populating search results?

Comment: I have tried to add that at the end of the 'connectionDidFinishLoading' method, but unfortunately this does not help.

Comment: I deleted the tableview, used '[[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] reloadData];' and did more tinkering with my search methods and got it to kinda work. Your answer got me back on the right track, so I'll give it to you.